# Do 'starts_with' and 'start_with' have the same function in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Apparently they are giving me the same output on any input like

```
"Ruby is red".start_with?("Ruby")
```

or

```
"Ruby is red".starts_with?("Ruby")
```

both are giving the same result.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Before Ruby added `String#start_with?` as part of the core library, Rails' Active Support implemented the `String#starts_with?` method. Now it's just an alias kept for backwards compatibility.

So yes - they do the same thing, the first one comes from Ruby, the second one - from Rails.

Comment: It looks like `starts_with?` is gone now. https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39152

Comment: @Qwertie not yet, but probably some time in the near future.

Comment: I think I might have found an older PR of this change. I found this post because the methods were gone in 6.1.